# The Draw method of IDrawable is not always called during a call to Invalidate

Tags: maui

I try to animate the content of a GraphicsView,

```
private void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var animation = new Animation(v => AngleSpan = v, 0, 360D, Easing.CubicInOut);
    animation.Commit(this, "AngleAnimation", 8, 1500);
}
```

but the animation is jerky (20ips when 8ms delay between two images should bring me closer to 120ips).

By adding a Debug.WriteLine before the call to Invalidate of the GraphicsView and in the Draw method of my IDrawable, I realize that the Draw method is called only one time out of 3 on average.

```
Invalidate
Invalidate
Draw
Invalidate
Invalidate
Draw
Invalidate
Invalidate
Invalidate
Draw
Invalidate
Invalidate
Invalidate
Draw
[...]
```

Isn't the call to Invalidate supposed to ensure that the Draw method is always called?

If it is not the case, what alternative do I have to have a smooth animation?

**EDIT**

I'm adding some context and clarifications related to the questions asked in comments:

The animation triggers the call to "Invalidate" via the setter of the AngleSpan property.

```
public class PieChart : GraphicsView
{
    private double _angleSpan = 360D;
    public double AngleSpan 
    {
        get => _angleSpan;
        private set
        {
            _angleSpan = value;
            Debug.WriteLine("Invalidate");
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public PieChart() 
    {
        Drawable = new PieChartDrawable(this);

        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded -= OnLoaded;
        
        var animation = new Animation(v => AngleSpan = v, 0, 360D, Easing.CubicInOut);
        animation.Commit(this, "AngleAnimation", 8, 1500);
    }
}
```

For testing purposes, I removed the content of Draw, thinking that the problem came from a too complex drawing, but with or without content, the problem remains the same.

```
public class PieChartDrawable : IDrawable
{
    private readonly PieChart _chart;

    public PieChartDrawable(PieChart chart) 
    { 
        _chart = chart;
    }

    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Draw");
    }
}
```

I tested with and without debugger attached (in debug and in release), same thing in all cases.

I haven't tested on mobile or emulator yet (only on a windows project, since that's what I'm interested in first).

Comment: You'll need to give more details. If you've started an animation, shouldn't it run by itself? The examples I've seen don't have an explicit `Invalidate`. Where are you calling `Invalidate`? Is this a test on Windows or what? [If its a mobile emulator, test on actual device.] Have you tried running WITHOUT debugger, to see if it runs more smoothly? Have you done the simplest possible test: a small solid color object, with nothing else in the view? Sounds to me like something is causing `Draw` to "take too long", so multiple Invalidates happen before the graphics system is ready to draw again.

Comment: You can check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/graphicsview#invalidate-the-canvas). It tells about Invalidate. And could you provide some more code so that I can reproduce the situation you described.

Comment: @JianweiSun I know this part of the documentation, and it is precisely this part that makes me say that a call to invalidate from GraphicsView necessarily implies a call to Draw from its Drawable. As for providing a piece of code to reproduce the problem, everything is already in my edit; just put PieChart on the MainPage of a default maui project, run it and see in the console that the Draw method is not systematically called (contrary to what the doc implies).

Comment: @JeremyA. Copy that. By the way, have you tried to generate `.apk` file and test on actual device to see if it has a smooth animation?

Comment: @JianweiSun Strangely, on a physical android device, each call to Invalidate method triggers a redraw (and the animation is smooth).
I tested on different PCs to see if my problem came from my config (Rysen 7 5800 + RX6600 + 32GB ram), but the problem occurs on any Windows machine (intel or amd, dedicated or integrated gpu).

Comment: Was the `.exe` file running on the PC? Or did it run directly in VS?

Comment: @JianweiSun I tried both; from vs (with or without debugger attached) and by directly running the exe built in release without vs.

Comment: Is there any error info on Windows?

Comment: There is no error anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the culprit; namely my screen.

If I switch the refresh rate of my screen to 60Hz, I don't have any problem anymore (Draw is called at each Invalidate).

[image: Display settings]

Basically:

- 60Hz -> 60fps
- 165Hz -> 20~30fps

Note that in 60Hz everything is smoother in my application, drag & drop, list scrolling, etc.. This is not limited to my canvas story.

I tested with a WPF and UWP app, I don't have this global low refresh rate concern. It looks like a bug on the WinUI side.

This means that in its current state it is not possible to have better conditions than a refresh rate of 60 fps with a WinUI (Maui Windows) app, and that if the end user has a high refresh rate screen, his experience will be highly degraded.